# How to get Playlist Id(s) containing given Video Id via youtube-api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

At first glance, I can only retrieve playlists by id. Never related or containing a video id:

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=RDRgKAFK5djSk&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I only need the playlist meta data, so if possible without having to authenticate, except by key.

**Bottomline:**

If you click a video on youtube, 1 of the suggested items at the right of your screen is a playlist which contains the current video and multiple related video's.

I want to get that playlist or a list of video's that is very simular to this result. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I think the best way to get the list of playlists that contain a certain video is by using the `search.list` [request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). You will have to specify `type=playlist` and the title of the video for the `q` parameter. Note that this may not give you the playlists you're expecting if the title of the video isn't specific enough.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=VIDEO_TITLE_HERE&type=playlist&key=API_KEY_HERE
```